# Does PHP have a similar solution to C# with create an array of new objects with getter and setters

Tags: c#, php, get, set

Is there a way to do what you can do in C# (pseudo code):

```
class User
{
     $FirstName = { get; set; }
     $LastName = { get; set; }
}

$array = array(
    new User { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Wibbly" },
    new User { FirstName: "Yank", LastName: "Anchor" }
)
```

Or do I need to use constructor parameters?

I only ask because I was wondering if the __Get and __Set methods were suppose to do something clever here.

EDIT::

So If I use set_state:

```
class User
{
     public $FirstName = { get; set; }
     public $LastName = { get; set; }

     public function __set_state( $param )
     {
          $obj = new User;
          $obj = $param[ 'FirstName' ];
          $obj = $param[ 'LastName' ];
          return $obj;
     }    
}
```

// How do I now do this part: ?

```
$array = array(
    new User { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Wibbly" },
    new User { FirstName: "Yank", LastName: "Anchor" }
)
```

Comment: [Check out the PHP5 Magic Methods documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: That will definitely do the trick for you!

Comment: @DevlshOne - Could you give me a hand with my question now, I've added an edit bit :( I'm confused